# How to extract efficiently multiple columns from a single string column RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a file with 20+ columns of which I would like to extract a few. Until now, I have the following code. I'm sure there is a smart way to do it, but not able to get it working successfully. Any ideas?

mvnmdata is of type RDD[String]

````scala
val strpcols = mvnmdata.map(x => x.split('|')).map(x => (x(0),x(1),x(5),x(6),x(7),x(8),x(9),x(10),x(11),x(12),x(13),x(14),x(15),x(16),x(17),x(18),x(19),x(20),x(21),x(22),x(23) ))```
````

Comment: What kind of error appeared when above code was executed? Is it some thing like "too many elements for tuple"?

Comment: There was no error, I got the expected result. But I was thinking if there is a shortway to write the same command without the "x(n)" being repeated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As below,if you don't want to write repeated x(i),you can process it in a loop. Example 1:

```
val strpcols = mvnmdata.map(x => x.split('|'))
  .map(x =>{
    val xbuffer = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
    for (i <- Array(0,1,5,6...)){
      xbuffer.append(x(i))
    }
    xbuffer
  })
```

If you only want to define the index list with start&end and the numbers to be excluded, see Example 2 of below:

```
scala> (1 to 10).toSet
res8: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 10, 1, 6, 9, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4)

scala> ((1 to 10).toSet -- Set(2,9)).toArray.sortBy(row=>row)
res9: Array[Int] = Array(1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10)
```

The final code you want:

```
  //define the function to process indexes
  def getSpecIndexes(start:Int, end:Int, removedValueSet:Set[Int]):Array[Int] = {
    ((start to end).toSet -- removedValueSet).toArray.sortBy(row=>row)
  }

  val strpcols = mvnmdata.map(x => x.split('|'))
    .map(x =>{
      val xbuffer = new ArrayBuffer[String]()
      //call the function
      for (i <- getSpecIndexes(0,100,Set(3,4,5,6))){
        xbuffer.append(x(i))
      }
      xbuffer
    })
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for!

Comment: Sorry, did not see that. Not able to change it now. The solution above doesn't work in my version(Scala 2.11), which version did you write this in?

Comment: Can you describe what the error you meet? My Scala version is 2.11 too.

Comment: I didn't have the correct import defined which I did after. Can it be further shortened to just define only the start, end and the index numbers to be excluded?

Comment: Yes, it cloud be completed as the Example 2 above.

Comment: It's very close now. Two things: Instead of "1" and "10", can we make it more generic? like x.start & x.end, I tried and it didn't work though. Secondly, how do I merge your second answer in to the first?

Comment: You can just define a function, and then call the function in the Eample 1's map block.

Comment: Now I have written the final code above.The function getSpecIndexes is just what you want.Just see it .

Answer (score 0):

The next solution provides an easy and scalable way to manage your column names and indices. It is based on a map which determines the column name/index relation. The map will also help us to handle both the index of the extracted column and its name.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StringType, StructType, StructField}

val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
"1|500|400|300",
"1|34|67|89",
"2|10|20|56",
"3|2|5|56",
"3|1|8|22"))

val dictColums = Map("c0" -> 0, "c2" -> 2)

// create schema from map keys
val schema = StructType(dictColums.keys.toSeq.map(StructField(_, StringType, true)))

val mappedRDD = rdd.map{line => line.split('|')}
                    .map{
                      cols => Row.fromSeq(dictColums.values.toSeq.map{cols(_)})
                    }

val df = spark.createDataFrame(mappedRDD, schema).show

//output
+---+---+
| c0| c2|
+---+---+
|  1|400|
|  1| 67|
|  2| 20|
|  3|  5|
|  3|  8|
+---+---+
```

- First we declare `dictColums` in this example we will extract the cols "c0" -> 0 and "c2" -> 2
- Next we create the schema from the keys of the map
- The one map (which you already have) will split the line by `|`, the second one will create a `Row` containing the values that correspond to each item of `dictColums.values`

**UPDATE:**

You could also create a function from the above functionality in order to be able to reuse it multiple times:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def stringRddToDataFrame(colsMapping: Map[String, Int], rdd: RDD[String]) : DataFrame = {
  val schema = StructType(colsMapping.keys.toSeq.map(StructField(_, StringType, true)))

  val mappedRDD = rdd.map{line => line.split('|')}
                    .map{
                      cols => Row.fromSeq(colsMapping.values.toSeq.map{cols(_)})
                    }

  spark.createDataFrame(mappedRDD, schema)
}
```

And then use it for your case:

```scala
val cols = Map("c0" -> 0, "c1" -> 1, "c5" -> 5, ... "c23" -> 23)

val df = stringRddToDataFrame(cols, rdd)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I need a bit of time to understand what is happening behind each of the steps! Appreciate your time.

Comment: Sure take your time. In between here are some further details: 1. we create schema based on the keys of the dictColums map. First we create a StructType which should be filled with StructField s by mapping each key to a new StructField instance where key is the name and the type will be of StringType (you could change this to support more types if you wish to). In our case c0, c1 will be the column names of the schema. 2. we split each row on `|` this will produce an array of strings

Comment: 3. for each array we produce a new instance of Row containing elements we extract with `dictColums.values.toSeq.map{cols(_)}`. The last one extracts the desired columns from the array using the values of the dictionary which actually will be the desired array indexes. The indexes will be 0 for c0 and 2 for c2. The values that correspond to those two `x(0), x(2)` will be also the content of the new created Row. 4. finally we populate a new dataframe using mappedRDD and schema