# Fixed length parsing in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parsing, fixed-length-file

I have created the dataframe and the input is like this:

```
   +-----------------------------------+
   |value                              |
   +-----------------------------------+
   |1   PRE123                    21   |
   |2   TEST                      32   |
   |7   XYZ                       .7   |
   +-----------------------------------+
```

and on the basis on the below metadata information we need to split the above data frame and create a new dataframe, having columns name id,name and class and it start and index loction is given in this json meta data.

```
   {
    "columnName": "id",
    "start": 1,
    "end": 2
  },
  {
    "columnName": "name",
    "start": 5,
    "end": 10
  },
  {
    "columnName": "class",
    "start": 20,
    "end": 22
  }
```

OUTPUT :

```
  +---+------+-----+
  | id|  name|class|
  +---+------+-----+
  |  1|PRE123|   21|
  |  2|  TEST|   32|
  |  7|   XYZ|   .7|
  +---+------+-----+
```

For loading the df, I have created the list:

```
   list.+=(loadedDF.col("value").substr(fixedLength.getStart, (fixedLength.getEnd - fixedLength.getStart)).alias(fixedLength.getColumnName))
```

and from this list, I have created the dataframe

```
var df: DataFrame = loadedDF.select(list: _*)
```

Need to know the order better approach for creating the dataframe from the metadata. 
As the list created will bring all the data to the driver node.

Comment: Hi Etisha it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide a simple example with the input and the desired output? Also what is fixedLength/metadata and how are they related with your requirements?

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis Please see the post again.

Comment: Etisha do you have strict requirement to maintain a fixed length for all your data? The solution below is more flexible and does not require to provide any fixed start/end variables. In this case the only metadata you need is the column name. The code then would be more maintainable and simple

Comment: Yes.  We have strict requirement to maintain a fixed length for all your data and it will be dynamic.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56147168/how-to-extract-efficiently-multiple-columns-from-a-single-string-column-rdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you requirements you are trying to extract the columns from a string separated by an arbitrary number of spaces.

Here is one solution with substr function:

```scala
val df = Seq(
  ("1   PRE123         21"),
  ("2   TEST           32"),
  ("7   XYZ            .7"))
.toDF("value")

val colMetadata = Map("id" -> (1,2), "name" -> (5,10), "class" -> (20,22))

val columns = colMetadata.map { case (cname, meta) => 
  val len = meta._2 - meta._1   
  $"value".substr(meta._1, len).as(cname)
}.toSeq

df.select(columns:_*).show
```

And a generic solution when you don't have the column boundaries available using the split function:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.split

val df = Seq(
  ("1   PRE123         21"),
  ("2   TEST           32"),
  ("7   XYZ            .7"))
.toDF("value")

val colNames = Seq("id", "name", "class")

val columns = colNames.zipWithIndex.map { case (cname, idx) =>
      split($"value", "\\s+").getItem(idx).as(cname)
}

df.select(columns:_*).show
```

Output:

```
+---+------+-----+
| id|  name|class|
+---+------+-----+
|  1|PRE123|   21|
|  2|  TEST|   32|
|  7|   XYZ|   .7|
+---+------+-----+
```

Notice that I used `\\s+` as separator. This represents a regex for **one or more spaces**.